# How to write a basic if statement to compare 3 variables and return the largest?

Tags: python

I need a basic if statement that looks at 3 variables and returns the largest.

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

if a>=b and a>=c:
  return a
elif b>=a and b>=c:
  return b
elif c>=a and c>=b:
  return c
```

1. Is this correct way to write this simple logic using IF statements? For example can I replace the last elif with else and skip the elif check?
2. Is there a pythonic way to write this?

Comment: The Pythonic way is `max(a,b,c)`

Comment: 1. Did you test it? And... did you test it?

Comment: The last `elif` is unnecessary. Exactly one of the three is the maximum value (subject to your implied constraint that ties are broken by name), so if neither `a` nor `b` is the maximum, then it must be `c`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest u to check out the comment above, because its more correct.

But if u need if-else solution, u can do it more easier:

```
a, b, c = 10, 20, 30

# consider a to be the largest
if a >= b and a >= c:
  return a
# now we can say that a is not the largest one, and work with b, c only
elif b >= c:
  return b
# now we now, that a and b are not the largest
# else is optional here, and u can just write 'return c'
else:
  return c
```

Comment: If you hated your coworkers you could also do `return a if a >= b and a >= c else b if b >= c else c`

Comment: Did you commit smth like that as an easter egg? :D

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY need to use IF...

```
def maxif(a,b,c):
  if b <= a >= c:
    return a
  elif a <= b >= c:
    return b
  elif b <= c >= a:
    return c

print(maxif(1,2,3))
print(maxif(1,3,2))
print(maxif(2,1,3))
print(maxif(2,3,1))
print(maxif(3,1,2))
print(maxif(3,2,1))
```

Or...

```
def maxif(a,b,c):
  if b <= a >= c:
    return a
  elif b >= c:
    return b
  else:
    return c

print(maxif(1,2,3))
print(maxif(1,3,2))
print(maxif(2,1,3))
print(maxif(2,3,1))
print(maxif(3,1,2))
print(maxif(3,2,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're insistent on not using *max()* then:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    return a if b <= a >= c else b if b >= c else c
```

Of course, this is limited to testing exactly 3 variables and is therefore of little use in the real world

Comment: and shows that you do hate your co-workers :-)

Comment: That wouldn't be too bad with some parentheses around the conditions.

Comment: @kindall This is not meant as a serious answer. *max()* is the way to go (as has been said several times). Just because a piece of code works doesn't make it right

Comment: also see my pre-existing comment in the above answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596127/218663 :-P

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass an array to the `max` function like this:

```py
max([10, 20, 30])
```

**Edit:** You don't even need to pass it in as an array since you can pass all variables as separate arguments to the `max` function

Comment: I'm looking for way to write this using IF for my own understanding.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a list, just pass in the three values.

Comment: Why do you need to write it using an if statement when that isn't the best way to do it? Is there any context in which you intend to use this that you haven't included in your question?

Comment: For my own understanding of writing logic

Comment: If you NEED to use if statements then there is no better way to do it. However, the pythonic way would be to use the `max` function

Comment: There seems to be better way as suggested by other answer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596127/1779091

Comment: @variable Part of understanding is knowing when to use abstractions like `max` instead of brute-force comparisons.

Comment: This is purely for my understanding of basic IF blocks and logic

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but the pythonic way of doing it is:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

return max(a,b,c)
```

Comment: There is an answer above that mentions this option